# Inserting checkbox values into database in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn how to build an application using Spring MVC and Hibernate. Currently I am stuck on inserting checkbox values into MySQL database.

My Database Table Structure is like following:

```
 id    name    interest
```

When I fill up my form and hit submit I get this error message :

root cause

*java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05ur...' for column 'interest' at row 1
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)*

I am trying to insert values in my table so that after insertion it looks like following:

```
 id    name    interest
 1    Steve    PHP
 2    Steve    Java
 3    Wuagh    C#
 4    Wuagh    PHP
```

Could you please tell me how to achieve this? And If possible could you also tell me how can I achieve this as well ?

```
id    name    interest
 1    Steve    PHP, Java
 2    Wuagh    C#, PHP
```

Please see my codes below

My Form:

```
<c:url var="action" value="/register" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${action}" modelAttribute="subscriber" method="POST" >

    <div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <form:input path="name"/>
    <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/> 
    </div>

    <div>
    <label>Interests</label>
    <form:checkboxes path="interest" items="${records.interests}"/>     
    </div>  

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form:form>
```

Controller:

```
package com.spring.org;
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
private SubscriberService subService;

@RequestMapping(value="/register", method= RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView RegistrationForm(@ModelAttribute Subscriber subscriber, BindingResult result)
{

  HashMap<Integer, String> interest = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    interest.put(1,"Java");
    interest.put(2,"PHP");
    interest.put(3, "C#");
    return new ModelAndView("regForm", "records", interest);
}


@RequestMapping(value="/register", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView RegistrationFormSubmit(@ModelAttribute("subscriber") @Valid Subscriber subscriber, BindingResult result)
{
    if (result.hasErrors()) {

        return new ModelAndView("regForm");
    }
    else
    {
        subService.addSubscriber(subscriber);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/showList");
    }
}

}
```

Model - Subscriber

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON", schema = "java2")
public class Subscriber {

  @Id
  @Column(name="ID")
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your Name.")
  private String name;
  private String[] interest;

 public String getName() {return name;} 
 public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
 public String[] getInterest() { return interest; }
 public void setInterest(String[] interest) { this.interest = interest; }

 }
```

SubscribeService Implementation :

```
@Service
public class SubscriberServiceImpl  implements SubscriberService{

 @Autowired 
 private SubscriberDao subsDao ;

 @Override
 public void addSubscriber(Subscriber subscriber) {

    subsDao.addSubscriber(subscriber);

 }
}
```

SubscriberDao Implementation :

```
@Repository
public class SubscriberDaoImpl implements SubscriberDao {


 @Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory ;

 public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
 }

 public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
 }

 @Override
 public void addSubscriber(Subscriber subscriber) {

    getSessionFactory().openSession().save(subscriber);     

 }
}
```

Comment: [This](http://javarticles.com/2015/06/spring-registering-custom-editor-example.html) link should help you some, as well as the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html). It's a data binding issue where the form will return the value as a String instead of whatever type it was initially.